# Show div element only on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the below code to hide / show div element. Now i wanna hide the element on page load. The div element should be displayed only on clicking the button.

```
<style type="text/css">
#sectiontohide {
padding:20px;
background:#f0f0f0;
width:400px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_div(id) {

   var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

   if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
      divelement.style.display = 'block';
   else
      divelement.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>JavaScript to show/hide a Div</h3>

<button onClick="toggle_div('sectiontohide');">Click here</button> to toggle  visibility of div element #sectiontohide
<br /><br />

<div id="sectiontohide">This is the div to hide with id = sectiontohide</div>
```

Comment: make sectionhide is "display: none" at first. then your code is perfect. i have one suggestion also use jquery to hide/show div like $("#" + id).toggle(); it will make smaller your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code on script block

```
window.onload = function () {
    toggle_div("sectiontohide");
};
```

Comment: Hi ... thanks ... It works fine but the div element flashes a sec before getting hide.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the css to hide it

```
<style type="text/css">
#sectiontohide {
  padding:20px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  width:400px;
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeings your using inline styling, why not just set it to begin with?

```
<div id="sectiontohide" style="display: none;">This is the div to hide with id = sectiontohide</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the div's visible hidden option.

```
<div id="sectiontohide" style='display:none'>This is the div to hide with id = sectiontohide</div>
```